# Best practice for handling class fields that require a server call

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection, software-design

I have a class field that I want to assign the result of a dependency call to.
Where is the best place to do the dependency call, an HTTP call to a server, and assign the result?

Take this class for example:

```py
@dataclass
class User:
    id: str
    username: str = "" # Unknown at initialization stage, requires http call to get username based in id
```

In this context:

```py
user = User(id='12345')
result = dummy_library.get_username(user.id) # call to a server and return result
user.username = result.username
```

I have a few options in mind, however, I'm unable to come to a decision on which one to use:

#### Option 1: Assign `username` in a try/except in `__init__`

Pros:

- Simple

Cons:

- Hard to test, need to inject the `dummy_library` into class to call it

#### Option 2: Assign `username` in a try/except in `__post_init__`

Same as Option 1, except shifting work to **post_init**

#### Option 3: Assign `username` in an instance function

```py
class User:
...
    def set_username(self, dummy_library):
        try:
            result = dummy_library.get_username(user.id) # call to a server and return result
            user.username = result.username
        except:
            ...
...
user = User(id='12345')
user.set_username(dummy_library)
```

Pros:

- Easy to unit test with dependency injection

Cons:

- Redundant, must call `set_username` after each `User` instantiation

#### Option 4: Get `username` before initializing `User`

```py
try:
    user_id = '12345'
    result = dummy_library.get_username(id=user_id) # call to a server and return result
    user = User(id=user_id, username=result.username)
except:
    ...
```

Pros:

- Easy to unit test with dependency injection

Cons:

- Redundant, try/except for each User instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Make `username` a property and give it a default value.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id_, dummy_library, username=None):
        self.id = id_
        self._username = username
        self._dummy_library = dummy_library

    @property
    def username(self):
        if self._username is None:
            try:
                self._username = self._dummy_library.get_username(self.id)
            except:
                print('error')
        return self._username


u = User(42, dummy_library)
print(u.username)
```

Pros:

- All username fetching logic is in one place
- Can be easily tested by passing patched/fake `dummy_library` (or actually passing a `username`) to `User`
- The API call is delayed until the first time we try to access `.username`, and it is only done once (unless `username` is explicitly set to `None`).

Notice that a setter is not implemented, but it can be if additional logic is required.